# I am getting a module error in my django project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a new django application and for some reason I am getting an error while i am trying access the models from the models.py file from the forms.py file.

Here is the error:

```
  File "/Users/omarjandali/Desktop/MySplit/mysplit/general/forms.py", line 13, in <module>
    from models import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

Yet I have the general app added to the installed settings. and I have all the models saved. Why is it saying that the module is not there... I am going blank. I know it is a simple answer but for some reason I cant figure it out.

here is the forms.py file:

```
# all model imports related to this project
from models import *

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

here is the models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager
from localflavor.us.models import USStateField, USZipCodeField

# the following is the users profile model
class Profile(models.Model):
    # users basic info
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='first')
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='last')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=220, default='bio')
    # users location
    street = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='street address')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='city')
    state = USStateField(default='CA')
    zip_code = USZipCodeField(default=12345)
    # users other profile info
    phone = models.IntegerField(default="000-ooo-oooo")
    dob = models.DateField(default='1950-01-01')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='Other')
    # lob = industry/occupation
    lob = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='occupation')
    # dba = Company Name
    dba = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='comapny')
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='INDIVIDUAL')
    synapse_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='123456789')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from .models import *
```

you need to provide the . for the path for same directory

also you can give absolute path

```
from app_name.models import *
```

Comment: I knew it would be someone super small. i forgot the `.models`

Answer (score 1):

```
from <app_name>.models import <class_name>
```

This will fix the problem. In your case, app_name is "mysplit" most probably

So, you need to import like this :

```
from mysplit import *
```

"*" because you are importing everything inside the models.py file
I hope this will resolve your issue